# Why my JavaScript code is printing undefined with the exception throwed?

Tags: javascript, exception

The Problem here is that with the output coming JavaScript also says undefined. I have seen some codes on w3schools.com and developers.mozilla websites and tried some other sites also but didn't find any solution or any explanation about the problem that i encounter.

I want to throw an exception when 0 or negative value occur.

```js
function isPositive(a) {

  try {
    if (a > 0) return "YES";

    if (a < 0) throw "Negative Value";

    if (a == 0) throw "Zero Value";
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}


console.log(isPositive(0));
```

Output expected was 
`"Zero Value"`

Actual Output is

```
"Zero Value" 

undefined
```

Any suggestions why my code prints undefined along with the output? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Where are you running this? Also, will you please post the rest of your code.

Comment: You don't return anything unless the result is positive. And why are you throwing in a `try`?

Comment: this is all code that i have. i am testing my code on jsbin.com. I have already tried without try and catch but it was not working.

Comment: You have *two* `console.log` in that code. What do you expect the second one to log?

Answer (score 1):

This is because if any error is thrown in `try` it doesnot stop execution of code. If you want to stop the function on error just remove that `try-catch` and simply `return`

```js
function isPositive(a){
    if(a>0) return "YES"
    if(a<0) return "Negative Value";
    if(a == 0) return "Zero Value";
}
console.log(isPositive(0));
```

If you want to throw error put the the statements out of `try`

```js
function isPositive(a){
    if(a>0) return "YES"
    if(a<0) throw ("Negative Value");
    if(a == 0) throw ("Zero Value");
}
console.log(isPositive(0));
```

Comment: I have also tried to put the if statements out of the try and catch block but it still doesn't work and giving "Uncaught Zero Value (line 12)".

Comment: @Amit Khatri So whats problem it that. If you want `"Zero Value"` only then use the first snippet

Answer (score 0):

```js
function isPositive(a){
try{
if(a>0) return "YES";

   if(a<0) throw "Negative Value";

   if(a == 0) throw "Zero Value";
}catch(err)
{
return err;
}
}


console.log(isPositive(0));
```

I find the answer and this code works for me and giving the proper results.

Answer (score 0):

You have `console.log(isPositive(a))` calling the function and if it throws error it returns **"undefined"** (and you will have it printed into console). But if you specify that you return the error it will print the **"Negative Error"**. Code bellow.

```
function isPositive(a) {
    try{
        if (a > 0) return "YES" 
        if (a  == 0) throw ('Zero Error');    
        if (a < 0) throw ('Negative Error');
    }
    catch(error){
        return(error);
    }
}
```